# Excel - Cells to change color based on previous cell value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a formula in Excel whereby a cell would change color based on the value in the previous cell.

for example if cell B2 contains value X and then B3 contains value Y, I would like B3 to turn green if B3> B2 else to turn red.

Comment: Did you try Highlight Cells in Conditional Formatting ?

Answer (score 1):

'Standard' fill red the relevant range and select Column B, clear any existing CF rules and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(B1>B1048576,ROW()<>1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

I am assuming your column is labelled.

Comment: You could also, select `B2:B1048576` insert conditional formatting, only format cells based on cellvalue > greater than > `=B1`